# Absolute stability for System with nonlinear output function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics

Given a nonlinear system like

$$
\begin{split}
\dot{x} &= Ax - B\phi(y)\\
y &= C^T x.
\end{split} \tag{1}
$$

If the nonlinear function $\phi$ fulfills the well known sector conditons on absolute stability, we can easily check for stability of the nonlinear system (at least we get sufficient conditions).

However, given a system like

$$
\begin{split}
\dot{x} &= Ax - B\phi(y) \\
y &= g(x)
\end{split} \tag{2}
$$

with the output $y$ being a nonlinear function of the state vector, $y = g(x)$.

**Question**: Is it still possible to analyse (absolute) stability of $(2)$ using the same (or similar) techniques as for system $(1)$? Only for certain kinds of $g$? Or are all bets off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A system in the form of $(2)$ can also be written in the form of $(1)$ using

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\dot{x} =\,& A\,x - B\,\phi(g(y)) \\
y =\,& x
\end{align}
\right. \tag{3}
$$

So $C$ is the identity matrix and the resulting nonlinear function is $\phi(g(y))$. After this you can use the same techniques for analyzing stability as for $(1)$.

Namely for stability analysis it does not matter how you define the output $y$, however this will affect the observability of the system.

Comment: But does this also work if $\phi(g(\cdot))$ requires multiple states as input? I thought this does only work for scalar outputs?

Comment: @SampleTime For when defining the function it shouldn't matter. But for the stability analysis I am not completely sure, but I think that it can be generalized to a cone, because I believe a MIMO function can still be a Lipschitz.

Comment: I ask because in many (if not all) lectures I have read so far, the assumption of a decentralized nonlinear function is made. This means that $\phi_i(y) = \phi_i(y_i)$. Therefore I wounder what can be done if this is not the case...

Comment: @SampleTime Maybe you can find a full rank $C$ matrix, or just a similarity transformation in $x$, such that the nonlinear function is decentralized.

Comment: @SampleTime The only assumption I saw in Nonlinear Systems from Khalil is that $y,u\in\mathbb{R}^p$, which might not be the case for $(3)$.

Comment: You are right with that... However, I thought a bit about your comment and I am not sure if I understood it right... you mean that it wont work because probably $\text{dim}(u) < \text{dim}(y)$? Can't I just extend $B$ with zero columns in that case to make both dimensions match?

Comment: @SampleTime that might indeed work, and it also should not make the problem much more difficult since the "cone" encloses a relatively small area.